# How to fix an ancient Windows XP start menu bug?

Tags: windows-xp, start-menu, drag-and-drop, pin

I dual-boot Windows 7 and Windows XP. I still use Windows XP for some old software, but I never allow it to go online - the ethernet drivers are disabled in case I forget to power off the cable modem.

Probably not long after I first used Windows XP, I noticed a minor bug in the start menu handling. Pinned items can be dragged and dropped to re-order them, but when you drop them, they drop in the wrong out-by-one position - one position *up* from where the mouse is aimed. The drop-line shows in the correct place where you'd expect it, but when you release the mouse button, the item drops in an out-by-one position.

This bug has always fixed itself in the past. I thought maybe the it was due to me installing from a prior-to-any-service-packs disk, and maybe the fix gets fixed by Windows Update. Except that now it doesn't, because I don't let Windows XP go online and therefore Windows Update isn't getting run. I install service pack 3, but this doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Since it's a minor issue, I've mostly just worked around it or ignored it, but I'd really like a fix for this if possible. It seems daft to put up with a bug that had a fix probably before even SP1 was released.

Any ideas?

For example is there a hotfix I could download now which for some bizarre reason Microsoft never included in a service pack?

Comment: XP and W7 are full of minor bugs like these, Microsoft will never fix them unfortunately, some of the XP bugs actually carried over to W7, thats how much they care.

Comment: @Moab - except that I *know* this bug was fixed, because most of my time using XP over the last 6 or 7 or however many years the bug wasn't there. And as for never fixing bugs - have you looked at how many bugfixes there are in SP3? And how many (particularly security hotfixes) have been released since then?

Comment: @Moab - Until about six months ago, I was dual-booting Windows XP and OpenSUSE 11.3 Linux. I bought Windows 7 because I was sick of the problems with Linux - admittedly the vast majority were driver issues that the Linux devs can't control, but the practical reality is that I couldn't keep Linux stable and the last straw was when became unbootable for no apparent reason. I haven't had that happen to me that I recall in any Windows release since Windows 98SE. Ignore Vista and Microsoft really aren't doing so bad.

Comment: Yes I know haw many big fixes there are, but the less annoying ones are always neglected by Microsoft. SP3 should address any past bugfix as it will be included.

Comment: @Moab - well, I don't know what fixed the issue in the past, so you may be right - it may have nothing to do with service packs or hotfixes. But if so, there must still be something I can do to resolve it - a registry hack or something. Like I said, it has resolved itself in the past - there must be some way to get into a resolved state from a non-resolved state because I've done it (without knowing how) a number of times in the past.

Comment: could it be because of any text "DPI" stretch you got going? there is never a miss with sorting a classic menu, yet this new skinned stuff is a bitmap with text tossed on top.

Comment: @Psychogeek - I'm not sure what you mean by DPI stretch. I'm referring to the default Windows XP start menu - not the older Windows 2000-style one which is called "classic" in XP - I'm guessing "classic" in Win7 means XP-style. I do select "small fonts" in the display settings, and small items in the menu. But the out-by-one is consistent - it's *not* out by a scale factor, but out by a constant offset, even on a start menu that's almost as tall as the screen.

Comment: I donno, I never use the "mouse position" , as I get a Line that shows where the drop is , just like in a toolbar, it is where the drop line shows. and I have never seen the behaviour change, or seen a text in a update that claims to address any of that. Even this comment needs a picture. http://i1107.photobucket.com/albums/h400/Psycogeec/MenuDrop.gif Using the Skinned menu, are you using the Original XP own unhacked skin and no hacks to the files or tweaks?

Comment: @Psychgeek - for me, the drop line shows in the right place, but that's not where the menu item drops when you let go of the mouse. I've just had another play (tried switching to classic and back - didn't work) so I'll edit the question to fix some errors and omissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install *all* the updates, or at least download everything for offline installation, you can use [wsus offline update](http://download.wsusoffline.net/). Without knowing which specific hotfix fixes it, this would probably be the best alternative

Comment: Great idea - download running now

Comment: The +1 was definitely earned, because that offline update is useful and I didn't know about it, but sadly it didn't fix the menu issue :-(